# How can I throw a general exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception

Consider this simple program. The program has two files:

#### File *Vehicle.java*

```
class Vehicle {
    private int speed = 0;
    private int maxSpeed = 100;

    public int getSpeed()
    {
        return speed;
    }

    public int getMaxSpeed()
    {
        return maxSpeed;
    }

    public void speedUp(int increment)
    {
        if(speed + increment > maxSpeed){
            // Throw exception
        }else{
            speed += increment;
        }
    }

    public void speedDown(int decrement)
    {
        if(speed - decrement < 0){
            // Throw exception
        }else{
            speed -= decrement;
        }
    }
}
```

#### File *HelloWorld.java*

```
public class HelloWorld {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle();
        Vehicle v2 = new Vehicle();

            // Do something

            // Print something useful, TODO
        System.out.println(v1.getSpeed());
    }

}
```

As you can see in the first class, I have added a comment ("// throw exception") where I would like to throw an exception. Do I have to define my own class for exceptions or is there some general exception class in Java I can use?

Comment: You might consider not throwing an exception at all, but rather just setting the speed to zero/maximum. Why punish callers for not knowing *exactly* how fast a car is going in order to stop/accelerate it?

Comment: Consider renaming `speedDown` to `slowDown`.

Comment: @dlev: agreed, but it's a matter of code design. The behaviour you're proposing matches a _normal_ car behaviour: accelerate up to limit top speed and slow down to full stop.

Comment: Coming from a C# background, I had the same question as Richard, to which none of the responses thus far seem to clearly answer.  In C#, you do not have to derive a new class from Exception.  You may simply "throw new Exception(message);" for example, and handle it generically in the block that will catch the exception.  I'm still developing my first Java app :-) but from the looks of things in the docs, Java is pretty much the same with respect to exceptions.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You could create your own Exception class:

```
public class InvalidSpeedException extends Exception {

  public InvalidSpeedException(String message){
     super(message);
  }

}
```

In your code:

```
throw new InvalidSpeedException("TOO HIGH");
```

Answer (score 44):

You could use IllegalArgumentException:

```
public void speedDown(int decrement)
{
    if(speed - decrement < 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Final speed can not be less than zero");
    }else{
        speed -= decrement;
    }
}
```

Comment: See my comment to previous similar answer. Also, beware of using `RuntimeException`s since the throwing method does not declare them.

Comment: [Direct link to Vlad's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942624/how-to-throw-a-general-exception-in-java#comment8274790_6942624) (to the question).

Answer (score 13):

Well, there are lots of exceptions to throw, but here is how you throw an exception:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("INVALID");
```

Also, yes, you can create your own custom exceptions.

A note about exceptions. When you throw an exception (like above) and you catch the exception: the `String` that you supply in the exception can be accessed throw the `getMessage()` method.

```
try{
    methodThatThrowsException();
}catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
{
  e.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Why is the argument illegal? Is there any check for argument value? Isn't the state illegal in fact `(speed < 0)` so he should throw an IllegalStateException?

Comment: Well the "State" of the object isn't illegal, the argument that was passed is illegal. (in this case decrement variable is illegal because its greater then the speed itself)

Comment: However you're checking the final state, not the argument's value. It's missleading. _What if_ `speed == 0` before calling `speedDown`?

Comment: @Vlad it all depens on how you look at it. if speed ==0 then all arguments are illegal. Either way my personal opinion I would go Illegal Argument

Comment: @Vlad: It's not checking the state at all.  You'll note that if the speed is out of range it's never assigned.  So the object is never in an illegal state.

Comment: I agree with Vlad. An IllegalArgumentException should only be thrown when the argument itself is incorrect. This should be unrelated to the state of the object. But Mark is right too, it's not an IllegalStateException either...

Comment: @Fortega for this situation if you don't want to create your own, IMHO I would said this is the best bet.

Comment: @RMT I don't see any reason to go for the second best option here. Why would you not want to create your own?

Comment: @Fortega, well there are numerous reasons, laziness is the main 1, lack of knowledge, faster just to use the ones that are all ready created.

Answer (score 8):

It really depends on what you want to do with that exception after you catch it. If you need to differentiate your exception then you have to create your custom `Exception`. Otherwise you could just `throw new Exception("message goes here");`

Comment: `Exception` is checked.  I'm not sure that would be productive here.

Comment: How is a `RuntimeException` more _productive_?

Comment: It doesn't make the caller deal with handling an exception that represents a programming error.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to do it would be something like:

```
throw new java.lang.Exception();
```

However, the following lines would be unreachable in your code. So, we have two ways:

---

1. Throw a generic exception at the bottom of the method.
2. Throw a custom exception in case you don't want to do 1.

Answer (score 4):

Java has a large number of built-in exceptions for different scenarios.

In this case, you should throw  an [`IllegalArgumentException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html), since the problem is that the caller passed a bad parameter.

Comment: An IllegalArgumentException should only be thrown in case of an inappropriate argument, and not if an appropriate argument causes a overflow somewhere. So I would throw an IllegalArgumentException in case of a negative argument and a custom exception when the max speed is exceeded.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own exception class extending java.lang.Exception (that's for a checked exception - these which must be caught), or extending java.lang.RuntimeException - these exceptions does not have to be caught.

The other solution is to review the Java API and finding an appropriate exception describing your situation: in this particular case I think that the best one would be `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. You can throw a more general exception, or a more specific exception. For simpler methods, more general exceptions are enough. If the method is complex, then, throwing a more specific exception will be reliable.