# How to return an error message (String) from a constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

Requirements:

1. Section is created by selecting one teacher, one subject and one
   schedule.
2. System verifies that all business rules are followed.

   - System detects that a business rule is not being followed.
   - System informs user of conflict.
   - System doesn't create new section.

3.System creates new section.

My problem is, if I define a constructor for section, Section(Teacher t, Subject s, Schedule c), I don't know how to return the error message for the conflict.

Should I just let my constructor throw an exception? If yes, how to return a string from a caught exception? How to create that exception?

Or is there any better, yet simple, implementation?

Comment: Like *all* exceptions, `throw exceptionObject` (either use an Unchecked Exception or use `throws`) to throw and `catch(SomeExceptionType e)` to handle. However, throwing all but the most dire exceptions from constructors is .. *icky* :( It is *extra* icky here because some business logic on the object graph would have to be handled in the ctor for it to be raised there.

Comment: look also on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371369/can-constructors-throw-exceptions-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reporting constructor failure boils down to two options:

1. Throw an exception as you suggest.  This is a reasonable approach if failure is not expected to happen often and is truly "exceptional".
2. If failure is a normal part of the business logic, I'd recommend using the Factory pattern and returning a wrapper object that contains the newly created object plus a status variable that can indicate the detailed causes of the failure when it occurs.

Answer (score 3):

You can throw the exception for sure.

```
throw new Exception("Some required files are missing");
```

Or create a new Exception to be used in your app (it will work the same way)

If you want to read the message inside of a try / catch statement just do this:

```
try
{
  // ...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); //this will get "Some required files are missing"
}
```

For more information checke these links out:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Throwing_and_Catching_Exceptions
[How to throw a general exception in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942624/how-to-throw-a-general-exception-in-java)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getMessage()

Comment: Throwing/Catching generic `Exception` instances typically isn't the best practice.  In this case if the author of the question didn't want to create their own custom exception throwing an `IllegalArgumentException` would probably be a reasonable replacement. That way unexpected exceptions aren't handled inadvertently.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to return a value from a constructor.  Your only way to do this is to throw an exception of some sort. You can either use an existing exception type (if there are any applicable) or create your own by extending `Exception`. For example:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

    public MyException(){
        super();
    }

    public MyException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Your constructor would simply throw a new instance of the exception and set an appropriate message. The code creating the class instance would catch the exception and handle it. You can obtain the message at that point by calling `getMessage()`.