# How do I insert error message if no file is selected?

Tags: java, user-interface, error-handling

I am doing java. I have this "SELECT" option whereby the user will choose a file. Then "START" option to use the selected file for some purposes but how do I make sure that if the file is empty and when the user clicked "START", it will prompt error message?

I tried for other functions and it works, but for this "SELECT" option, it just doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
    btnSelect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent args) 
        {
            int i = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

            if (i == chooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
            {
                textField.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    });

    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent args)
        {
            String fileToPath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

            // If file is not selected, show error message
            if (fileToPath == null)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PLEASE SELECT 1 FILE!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
            }
        }
    });
```

However, instead of seeing the expected error message, I got this.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Volatility$3.actionPerformed(Volatility.java:204)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

How can I solve this??? Help needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `chooser` initalised?  What line is `204`? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: that line is `String filePath = chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();`

Comment: Sounds like `chooser` is `null` or, more probably, the return result of `chooser.getSelectedFile()` is null

Comment: @MadProgrammer but I cannot think of what to put except for null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JFileChooser#getSelectedFile` will return `null` if nothing is selected, so bascially you are currently doing something like...

```
null.getAbsolutePath();
```

Which, obviously, can be done, instead, you should be checking the state of the return value first, for example...

```
File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();

// If file is not selected, show error message
if (selectedFile == null)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "PLEASE SELECT 1 FILE!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
} else {
    String fileToPath = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a try-catch block?

```
try {

  textField.setText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    throw new SampleException(e);

} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Or you could just throw an exception: [How to throw a general exception in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942624/how-to-throw-a-general-exception-in-java)
Cheers!

Comment: Nope, this does not work as I need the fileToPath for some other purposes and if I code the fileToPath in `try`, the below coding which uses `fileToPath` will have error because it is restricted to the try. I'm new to Java so if I said anything wrong, please inform me.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Well it appears to be more complicated than I thought. I will let you know if I find anything. Sorry I couldn't be of any help.

Comment: oh ok then.. Thanks for providing help to me :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient solution, but it definitely works.

```
public static boolean isFileEmpty(File file) throws IOException {
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        int count = 0;
        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            count++;
        }

        if (count == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Basically this works by making a file reader that will attempted to read the file and a count variable that will keep track of the amount of lines the file reader has read. If the loop ends and count is still 0, that means the file reader didn't read any lines and therefore must be empty. This is all wrapped up in a try catch to make sure a) the file exists and b) the file parameter has been initialized and is not null.

Comment: I realize now that I may have misinterpreted your question. You said "how do I make sure that if the file is empty", which made me think you wanted to check for an empty file, not an empty path.

Comment: Oh, it's ok! My problem is solved. Thanks for providing me your help :)

Comment: No problem. If you have any other questions, I'd be glad to help out.

Comment: You're not closing your streams, which could lead to file locks issues

Comment: And wouldn't an empty file simply be 0 bytes long?  What if the file contained nothing more the line breaks??

Comment: It doesn't matter at this point, but yes, good eye with the streams. My original intent was to make it a try with resources block which doesn't require you to close the stream manually. I guess I just forgot about it. And yes, an empty file would be 0 bytes long, so you could just use file.length(), but its whatever.