# Something's wrong with my endTime in java

Tags: java, windows, user-interface, cmd

I am trying to add a StartTime and EndTime to my java GUI as there will be multiple batch files running which will close one cmd, start another cmd, close this cmd and start another till all batch files are executed (the batch files will run based on the user's options).

When the user clicked on "START" option, the batch files will run. And then the StartTime has been recorded but will not display until all cmd is closed (that's what I found out after implementing). **When the processes ended, the StartTime displayed is correct. But the EndTime displayed is the same as StartTime which is wrong.** How can I solve this?

Here's my coding:

```
// Get system time
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

// startTime GUI texts
JLabel startTimeLabel = new JLabel("Start Time: ");
startTimeLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
startTimeLabel.setBounds(100, 245, 180, 53); 
contentPane.add(startTimeLabel);
JStartTimeTextField = new JTextField(); 
JStartTimeTextField.setBounds(170,265,200,15);
contentPane.add(JStartTimeTextField);
JStartTimeTextField.setColumns(10);

// endTime label
JLabel endTimeLabel = new JLabel(" End Time: ");
endTimeLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12));
endTimeLabel.setBounds(100, 265, 180, 53);
contentPane.add(endTimeLabel);
JEndTimeTextField = new JTextField(); 
JEndTimeTextField.setBounds(170,285,200,15);
contentPane.add(JEndTimeTextField);
JEndTimeTextField.setColumns(10);

//when start button is selected
btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent args)
    {
        //StartTime
        JStartTimeTextField.setText(dateFormat.format(date)); 

        try 
        {   
            //create new process    
            String[] command = new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "start", "/wait", DetectDrive+"\\Starting.bat", filePath}; 

            //run process
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

            //cause this process to stop until process p is terminated
            p.waitFor();
        } 
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(checkbox.isSelected())
        {
            try
            {   
                String[] command = new String[]{"cmd", "/c", "start", "/wait", DetectDrive+"\\Stage1.bat", filePath}; 
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                p.waitFor();
            } 
            catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ... (more coding on checkbox options)

        //The processes end
        JEndTimeTextField.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
    }
});
```

I find that my coding looks fine. But then.. Why is the StartTime and EndTime the same when all processes ended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`// Get system time
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");`

You are creating 1 Date variable and you use it:
Here: `JStartTimeTextField.setText(dateFormat.format(date));` and
here `JEndTimeTextField.setText(dateFormat.format(date));`

When you initialize the date, it does not change as time progresses.

For this code to work as expected, you need to get the new date and time at the end of the program instead of using the once you initialized in the beginning.

`//The processes end
Date newDate = new Date();
JEndTimeTextField.setText(dateFormat.format(newDate));`

Comment: Yes, but when i clicked, it called me to wait for 3 mins

Comment: if you happen to know java well, do you mind if you help me with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292465/how-do-i-insert-error-message-if-no-file-is-selected   ??

Answer (score 0):

In your code, can't find the end time initialization and used the same date instance for start time and end time.

Try with this,

```
   //The processes end
    JEndTimeTextField.setText(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the obvious...

Swing is a single threaded framework, that is call interactions, modifications and event dispatching should occur within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  Anything that stops this thread will prevent it from updating the UI, making it look like your program has hung, because it basically has...

So, the following is the key to your first problem...

```
p.waitFor();
```

This is blocking the event dispatching thread, preventing it from updating the UI until the process returns and the `actionPerformed` method exists.

To fix this, I suggest you implement a `SwingWorker`, which will allow you to run the process in the background, but provides methods by which the UI can be safely updated.

```
public class ProcessWorker extends SwingWorker<Date, Date> {

    public static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    private String[] commands;
    private JTextField endTimeField;

    public ProcessWorker(JTextField endTimeField, String... commands) {
      this.commands = commands;
      this.endTimeField = endTimeField;
    }

    @Override
    protected Date doInBackground() throws Exception {
      Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
      p.waitFor();
      return new Date();
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
      try {
        Date date = get();
        endTimeField.setText(DATE_FORMAT.format(date));
      } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

}
```

Which could then be called using something like...

```
ProcessWorker pw = new ProcessWorker(JEndTimeTextField, "cmd", "/c", "start", "/wait", DetectDrive + "\\Stage1.bat", filePath);
pw.execute();
```

Your second problem appears to be simpler (but since some code has been cut from the original, it's impossible to be sure), you are updating the end time with the same `Date` value you used for the start time...

```
JStartTimeTextField.setText(dateFormat.format(date));

//...

//The processes end
JEndTimeTextField.setText(dateFormat.format(date));
```

You simply need to create a new instance of `date` before you apply it to the `JEndTimeTextField`

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for more details

Comment: If he is just displaying start and end times, it wouldn't matter if the UI is updated during the process or not. But you're right.

Comment: @Error As a user, I would disagree, the UI could be make to display an infinite wait indicator, letting me know that it's processing, otherwise I'm left there wondering if the program has hung or not, better to put the user at ease