# Date Validation in Constructor with Try Catch

Tags: java

I need to make a `Date` class and in this `Date` class I need a constructor that validates a date in "**mm/dd/yyyy**" format. Additionally, it needs to throw an exception of type `Exception` if the parameter for the constructor does not match the date format. The class requires the fields month, day, and year to be integers. If the incoming parameter does not meet the date format, I need to set all fields to 0.

For the life of me, I cannot catch the exceptions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Date 
{
   private int month;
   private int day;
   private int year;
   private String date;

   public Date(String aDate)
   {
      date = aDate;
      String[] str = date.split("/");
      String sMonth = str[0];
      String sDay = str[1];
      String sYear = str[2];
      month = Integer.parseInt(sMonth);
      day = Integer.parseInt(sDay);
      year = Integer.parseInt(sYear);

      try
      {
          if (month <= 12 && day <= 31)
          {
              month = month;
              day = day; 
          }
          if (sYear.length() != 4)
          {
          year = year;
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         month = 0;
         day = 0;
         year = 0; 
      }      
 }
}
```

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment?

Comment: Rolling-your-own date class as a homework assignment, and gathering input from a user, and throwing/catching exceptions, has been handled many times already on Stack Overflow. Please search before posting. See [Oracle Tutorial on exeptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/). [How to throw a general exception in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6942624/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to int first:

```
date = aDate;
String[] str = date.split("/");
String sMonth = str[0];
String sDay = str[1];
String sYear = str[2];

try
{
    // Here you compare String to an int, do the convertions to int first
    // to make it throw exception on non integers.
    if (month <= 12 && day <= 31)
    {
        month = month = Integer.parseInt(sMonth);
        day = Integer.parseInt(sDay); 
    }
    if (sYear.length() != 4)
    {
    year = Integer.parseInt(sYear);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   month = 0;
   day = 0;
   year = 0; 
}
```

### Update

You need to validate yourself. It will need more validation than below, but just a hint.

```
try {
    // These can throw exceptions and you want to catch those too.
    month = Integer.parseInt(sMonth);
    day = Integer.parseInt(sDay);
    year = Integer.parseInt(sYear);

    if (month <= 12) {
        throw new Exception("month");
    }
    if (day <= 31) {
        throw new Exception("day");
    }    
    if (sYear.length() != 4) {
        throw new Exception("year");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    month = 0;
    day = 0;
    year = 0;
}
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot to change that back. Even with converting them to ints first, it still doesn't catch.

Comment: `Interger.parseInt("xx")` will throw an exception. If you want it to throw exceptions on invalid integers like month 100, you have to throw it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Java includes many libraries that can help you.
Visit: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-check-if-date-is-valid-in-java/

But if really need a constructor you need to add more validations.

i.e.

```
date = aDate;
String[] str = date.split("/");
String sMonth = str[0];
String sDay = str[1];
String sYear = str[2];

// Aux Variables
Integer m;
Integer d;

try {
    // Parse to Int, 
    // if Integer.parseInt cannot parse an Exception will be throw
    m = Integer.parseInt(sMonth);
    d = Integer.parseInt(sDay);

    // Check if months is in [1 - 12] range
    // Check if days is in [ 1 - 31] (You can add extra validations, i.e. for February)
    if (m > 0 && m <= 12 && d > 0 && d <= 31) {
        month = m
        day = d
    }

    if (sYear.length() != 4) {
        year = Integer.parseInt(sYear);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
   month = 0;
   day = 0;
   year = 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys! I really super greatly appreciate it! Thank for the fast turn around.