# Error 404 When Accessing Solr From Eclipse : Server at http://localhost:8983/solr was not found

Tags: java, eclipse, solr

I am using solr-6.4.0. I am able to install Solr, create a collection named "core1", index files using post command and also able to search for data from Solr through browser instance. I was using the following URL to access Solr: http://localhost:8983/solr/core1.
 Now when I am trying to access the above URL through eclipse, it gives the following error:

```
[main] ERROR SolrQuery - Generic Exception : Server at http://localhost:8983/solr was not found (404).

org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Server at http://localhost:8983/solr was not found (404).

    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:402)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:221)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.QueryRequest.process(QueryRequest.java:89)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.query(SolrServer.java:311)
    at SolrDataDAO.queryData(SolrDataDAO.java:36)
    at SolrQuery.testQueryData(SolrQuery.java:102)
    at SolrQuery.main(SolrQuery.java:74)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at SolrQuery.main(SolrQuery.java:89)
```

here is the code I am running:

```
public HttpSolrServer getSolrConnection() throws Exception
 {

        HttpSolrServer solrServer = null;
        try {
            // configure a server object with actual solr values.
            if (solrServer == null) {

                solrServer = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/core1");
                solrServer.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
                solrServer.setSoTimeout(5000);
                solrServer.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
            }

        } catch (Exception exc) {
            logger.error(" Exception in getting Solr Connection: "
                    + exc.getMessage());
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
        return solrServer;
    }
```

I used the same code with solr 4.5.0 and it was perfectly fine. but after upgradation its not working. please let me know what to update/include (jar files if any other).
thanks

Comment: you'll have to say what library you're using to communicate with solr.

Comment: @Jason a code snippet would be helpful. if you can please suggest edit

Comment: what code?  you have provided no information about what library you're actually using to connect to solr.  FWIW, my guess is whatever you're using needs to be updated.

Comment: I think this will help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942624/how-to-throw-a-general-exception-in-java

Comment: @jason anmol thanks for the comments. I have rectified the problem and code is working perfectly fine.